# Question about Tezos flagged as off topic

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm not sure why this question was closed / flagged as off-topic. It's about the code architecture in Tezos. Would like to hear rationale or how it should have been phrased [Test chain 48 hours constant](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/375/test-chain-48-hours-constant)

Answer (score 1):

Questions about the design of a language, project, etc [are off-topic for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design). The question is asking for the reason behind part of the design of Tezos.

The close reason, however, is not very explanatory. The question *is* about Tezos, but is off-topic for a totally different reason. I submitted a custom close reason explaining why I was voting to close, but it did not end up being the chosen description.

Comment: unlike the design of a programming language, Tezos primary innovation is that it is self-amending. Meaning that the design will be constantly evolving. And it is the community of developers who will discuss, debate, and build in those design changes. With that in mind, it seems questions about the motivations about the existing design and especially proposed new designs are in fact very important for this community.

Comment: I +1 on @cousinit comment since indeed the voting feature of tezos is precisely asking all community to assess the reason why certain design choices were and whether it is time to have them evolve. Tezos was designed such that the system can respond meta-questions about itself (should we change inflation ? Why consensus should be implemented this way vs that way etc)